# discord.js embeds: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body embed.fields[0].value: Must be 1024 or fewer in length

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am creating a discord bot that will take data from a website, and display it in an embed.
I stored the data in an array called `boxArr`. Then I iterate over it, store the data temporarly, and assign it to the correct embed's fields' properties (namely title and value).
It works fine for some pages, but not for others. Whenever if fails, I get an

`[UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body embed.fields[0].value: Must be 1024 or fewer in length.]` warning.
However the embed's values never exceeds 1024 characters in length, so I am baffled as to why I am getting this warning.

Here is my code:

```js
//Create the embed
var exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#2D2D2D')
    .setTitle(str)
    .setURL('/*page link here*/'+str)
    .setThumbnail(th)
    .addField('‌‌', def + `[Read More...](/*page link here*/${str})`);

    //Variable to hold the decision if titles are even or odd
    var toOdd = true;
    for(i = 0; (boxArr[i] != undefined || boxArr[i] != null); i++) {
        if(boxArr[i] === '' || boxArr[i].startsWith('"')) {
            if(isOdd(i) === 1) { //If boxArr[i] is nothing and i is odd, titles' location is when i is even
                toOdd = false;
                continue;
            } else { //If boxArr[i] is nothing and i is even, titles' location is when i is odd
                toOdd = true;
                continue;
            }
        }



        if(toOdd) {
            if(isOdd(i) === 1) {
                title = boxArr[i]; //Assign title its value
                i++; //Increment i
                val = boxArr[i]; 
   
                if(val === undefined || title === undefined) { //Check if one of the two is undefined. If yes then break out without tampering with the embed.
                  break;
                }
                Embed.addFields({name: title, value: val, inline: true});
                if(boxArr[i+1] === undefined) { //This is unnecessary but I added it nevertheless
                    break;
                }
                continue;  
            }
        } else if(!toOdd) { //Similar to if toOdd === true
            if(isOdd(i) != 1) {
                title = boxArr[i];
                i++;
                console.log('\n\nVALUE: '+ boxArr[i]);
                val = boxArr[i];
                if(val === undefined || title === undefined) {
                    break;
                }

                Embed.addFields({name: title, value: val, inline: true});
                if(boxArr[i+1] === undefined) {
                    break;
                }
                continue;  
            }
        }
                
    }
    
    message.channel.send(Embed); //send the embed
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the problem.
Apparently the problem is that the embed itself has over 1024 characters.
Removing `[Read More...](/*page link here*/${str})` from `.addField('‌‌', def + [Read More...](/*page link here*/${str}));` solved the problem.

EDIT: Another fix is to limit `str` to 500 characters.

Comment: Please mark your answer as correct if it is working properly.

Comment: I can do that in 4 hours.